# Method didDismissWithButtonIndex not firing from within singleton class

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to handle the dismissal event for a UIAlertView.  However didDismissWithButtonIndex never gets called.  Below is my code from the singleton class in which I am spawning the alert.  Can someone spot what I've done wrong?

**MySingleton.h**

```
@interface BMAppUser : NSObject <UIAlertViewDelegate> {

}

+ (id)sharedInstance;
```

**MySingleton.m**

```
+ (id) sharedInstance {
    static BMAppUser *sharedInstance = nil;
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (sharedInstance==nil) {
            sharedInstance = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
        }
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}

-(void)promptToSetLanguagePreferences {
// Create a new alert object and set initial values.
NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Please set your language preference settings.  Click OK to go there now."];

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Language Preferences Not Set"
                                                message:message
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
// Display the alert to the user
[alert show];
}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSLog(@"THIS METHOD NEVER GETS CALLED!!!!!!!");
    if(buttonIndex==0){
        NSLog(@"userclickedCancel");
    }
    if(buttonIndex==1){
        NSLog(@"userclickedOK");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have actually declared a method named `alertView::` not `alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` as you did not provide a name for the `UIAlertView` paramater to that method. This generated a compiler warning when I built it, namely:

> "'didDismissWithButtonIndex' used as the name of the previous
>   parameter rather than as part of the selector".

You need to provide a name for your `UIAlertView` parameter in your delegate method. Change the opening of its definition to the following:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```